# Unable to connect to ftp server java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I should be able to successfully send and receive file to/from FTP server.

But then, no changes occurred in the code and I started getting this :

> Error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

What I am doing is:

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

ftp.connect( IPADDRESS of FTP server);
```

`connect()` is giving this execption. I am not understanding the cause for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the OS's attempt to connect to the server timed out.  This typically means that:

- the remote server has dropped off the network, or
- something (e.g. a firewall) is "black holing" packets sent to the server on the FTP port.

Answer (score 0):

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port).

Source: [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html).

Comment: In this case it isn't 'connection refused', it is 'connection timed out'.